# How to display the raw value of my queryset

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have this function, to show my querysets:

```
funcionarios_aniver = FuncionarioAux.objects.filter(FuncionarioDataNasc__gte=dia_um, FuncionarioDataNasc__lte=ultimo_dia)
```

But it returns the querysets in an array, for example:

```
<QuerySet [<FuncionarioAux: Alberto Santos>, <FuncionarioAux: Josney Arman>]>
```

I would like it to return the raw values, like:

```
Alberto Santos, Josney Arman
```

I already tried using `.get()` at the end of the function, but I got the following error:

```
funcionarios.models.FuncionarioAux.MultipleObjectsReturned: get() returned more than one FuncionarioAux -- it returned 2!
```

what can I do to resolve?

Answer (score 0):

You can [evaluate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#when-querysets-are-evaluated) it for list of objects:

```
list(FuncionarioAux.objects.filter(FuncionarioDataNasc__gte=dia_um, FuncionarioDataNasc__lte=ultimo_dia))
```

Or you can loop through it to access individual objects:

```
for o in FuncionarioAux.objects.filter(FuncionarioDataNasc__gte=dia_um, FuncionarioDataNasc__lte=ultimo_dia):
     print(o)
```

You can get a flat list of values as a [values queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.values_list):

```
foobar = FuncionarioAux.objects.filter(FuncionarioDataNasc__gte=dia_um, FuncionarioDataNasc__lte=ultimo_dia).values_list('name', flat=True) 
print(foobar)  # use list(foobar) to get list of names instead of values queryset
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) so:

```py
list(FuncionarioAux.objects.filter(FuncionarioDataNasc__gte=dia_um, FuncionarioDataNasc__lte=ultimo_dia).values_list('name', flat=True))
```